# How do I print a row of random numbers that the user specifies?

Tags: c, srand, procedural

I'm writing a program that produces a unique sequence of random integers. It will ask the user for how many rows of random numbers they want to display, and the program will print a table of random numbers. The professor suggested using the `srand()` and `time(NULL)` functions in this program to make it work.

I've tried implementing the `srand` and `time` functions, but I haven't had any success. I've also tried writing a while statement but that hasn't been working out.

#### Code

```
int rows;
int main() {

        // Use srand() function to generate random numbers and print the rows that the user specified
        srand(time(NULL));
        //int rows;
        //int minRows = 0;
        //int maxRows = 15;
        printf("Please enter the number of rows you would like: ");
        scanf("%d", rows);
        while(rows<15) {
                printf("%d", rows);
         }
        return 0;
} //class main
```

I expect this program to print out the rows of random integers that the user specifies, but instead I get a 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' error after I try inputting the number of rows that I'd like.

Comment: the mistake is in your scanf it should be     scanf("%d", &rows);

Comment: while @Spinkoo is right, he doesnt address the problem in question. In the snippet you're just outputting the number of `rows` the user entered `rows` times. What you'd wanna do is first decide a boundary for your random numbers because they'll be in between 0 and `RAND_MAX`, say `upper_boundary`, then calling the `rand()` function like `printf("%d", rand() % upper_boundary)` within the loop. I strongly encourage you to check out [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm)  for the `rand()` function. And please, conduct a google search before asking.